# iPhone app: when App starts it stops the music player of the other app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, background, avaudioplayer

In my iPhone App to keep app running in background  I have implemented AVAudioPlayer which helps me to run timer in background mode and using timer it starts and stop updating location manager to preserve battery life.

Now the problem I am facing is: if some other app is playing music in background and I starts my app it stops the player of the app which is already running in background.

How can I make the music player running of the app which is running in background?

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways.

Comment: @Mike Weller  can u suggest me any proper way to achieve my it

Comment: @Prerak: Try setting `AVAudioSessionMode` to `Playback`.See if it helps. Let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: @Parth  AVAudioSessionMode is already Playback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you are abusing the background mode audio, which will get your app reject.
If you want to use location updates in the background just set the background mode to location.

And change the location manager to only tell you about a location change on major update.

The way you want to go is not an option, since there can only be one audio app running in the background at a time.

Comment: Here, I want to update location information at every 15 minute and want to save battery as well (not to keep lactation manager start updating all time) .so how can I achieve that?

Comment: No possible, you need to use the on majar change so that you will only be notified if the user is moving. That will even save more battery then to check every 15min.

Comment: Most things which are forbidden in iOS development are forbidden for a reason.